# How to get image of custom option from product detail page to Cart page

Tags: image, magento, xpath, cart

How to get image of custom option from product detail page to Cart page. offcourse i can get image download link, image name and its size..but i am unable to get image path to show image on cart page.

Try this by adding custom option image for any product by admin then browse image for it then press add to cart you can see the dowloadable link but not image..plz help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
Find this code on default.phtml on /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml

and replace with below code

<?php if ($_options = $this->getOptionList()):?>
        <dl class="item-options" style="width: 452px;">
            <?php foreach ($_options as $_option) :  ?>
            <?php $_formatedOptionValue = $this->getFormatedOptionValue($_option) ?>
            <dt><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_option['label']) ?></dt>
             <?php if($_option['label'] == 'Photo'){
              $photo = $_option['value'];
              $photo = str_replace("<a", "<img width='100' height='100'  style='float: right;'", $photo);
              $photo = str_replace("target", "", $photo);
              $photo = str_replace("href", "src", $photo);
              echo $photo."<br>";
                ?>
                <?php  }else{  ?>
            <dd<?php if (isset($_formatedOptionValue['full_view'])): ?> class="truncated"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $_formatedOptionValue['value'] ?>
                <?php if (isset($_formatedOptionValue['full_view'])): ?>
                <div class="truncated_full_value">
                    <dl class="item-options">
                        <dt><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_option['label']) ?></dt>
                        <dd><?php echo $_formatedOptionValue['full_view'] ?></dd>
                    </dl>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </dd>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
        <?php endif;?>
```